# subprocess.check_call gives error returned non-zero exit status 1

Tags: python, bash

I have a bash script that gets called at the end of Python script. If I call the script manually with a simple Python script (test.py below) it works fine. However when called from my actual script (long.py) it fails. So `long.py` runs, calling `rename.sh` at the end, and passing it a linux directory path, source_dir. `rename.sh` renames a file in said path. Here's a relevant excerpt of that script:

```
long.py

PATH = '/var/bigbluebutton/published/presentation/'
LOGS = '/var/log/bigbluebutton/download/'
source_dir = PATH + meetingId + "/"

...

def main():

...

    try:
        create_slideshow(dictionary, length, slideshow, bbb_version)
        ffmpeg.trim_audio_start(dictionary, length, audio, audio_trimmed)
        ffmpeg.mux_slideshow_audio(slideshow, audio_trimmed, result)
        serve_webcams()
        # zipdir('./download/')
        copy_mp4(result, source_dir + meetingId + '.mp4')

    finally:
        print >> sys.stderr, source_dir

        #PROBLEM LINE
        subprocess.check_call(["/scripts/./rename.sh", str(source_dir)])

        print >> sys.stderr, "Cleaning up temp files..."
        cleanup()
        print >> sys.stderr, "Done"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here's the problem:

`long.py` uses the above line to call `rename.sh`:

```
subprocess.check_call(["/scripts/./rename.sh", str(source_dir)])
```

it gives the error:

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/scripts/./rename.sh', '/var/bigbluebutton/published/presentation/5b64bdbe09fdefcc3004c987f22f163ca846f1ea-1574708322765/']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

The script otherwise works perfectly.

test.py, a shortened version of long.py, contains only the following two lines:

```
test.py

source_dir = '/var/bigbluebutton/published/presentation/5b64bdbe09fdefcc3004c987f22f163ca846f1ea-1574708322765/'
subprocess.check_call(["/scripts/./rename.sh", str(source_dir)])
```

It does not encounter the error when ran using python test.py.

Here's the contents of rename.sh:

rename.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash
i=$1

a=$(grep '<name>' $i/metadata.xml | sed -e 's/<name>\(.*\)<\/name>/\1/' | tr -d ' ')
b=$(grep '<meetingName>' $i/metadata.xml | sed -e 's/<meetingName>\(.*\)<\/meetingName>/\1/' | tr -d ' ')
c=$(ls -alF $i/*.mp4 | awk '{ gsub(":", "_"); print $6"-"$7"-"$8 }')
d=$(echo $b)_$(echo $c).mp4

cp $i/*.mp4 /root/mp4s/$d
```

`test.py` and `long.py` are in the same location.

I'm not executing `long.py` manually; it gets executed by another program.

```
print >> sys.stderr, source_dir
```

confirms that the exact same value as I define explicitly in test.py is getting passed by long.py to rename.sh

Comment: Why in the world would you write `d=$(echo $b)_$(echo $c).mp4` instead of `d="${b}_${c}.mp4`? The former is literally hundreds of times slower, not to mention buggier on account of the unquoted expansions in the command substitution expanding `$b` and `$c` as globs (changing `*` into a list of files in the current directory, f/e).

Comment: Anyhow, the error message is just saying that the last program your script ran (presumably `cp`) returned an error. The shell propagates that error back up, so the Python code receives it.

Comment: Consider running your shell script through http://shellcheck.net/. And don't use `grep` and `sed` to parse XML -- *especially* when called from Python code, which has a real XML parser and can do the job far more reliably (so you can pass `a`, `b`, etc. in as arguments). And add `set -x` to the shell script (after the shebang) to make it log the commands it runs, so you can better detect *why* it's failing.

Comment: ...that said, the time to ask a Stack Overflow question is after you've isolated *the shortest possible code* that causes a *narrow, specific problem*, and built the shortest possible reproducer others can run to see the problem themselves and test proposed answers (as described in the [mre] definition in the Help Center). Since this requires files nobody but you has, it isn't a reproducer others can run *at all*.

Comment: `rename.sh` could probably be re-written in Python - it would make debugging a whole lot easier and obviate the need for any subprocess routines.